# Setting up Traefik reverse proxy in docker on Unraid server

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, plex

I am not sure if this is the right place to post, if there is a better exchange site or forum in general please let me know!

I have a unraid box at 192.168.1.254

I want to setup some services in docker containers (plex, ombi, etc...) I am following this guide [here](https://github.com/duhio/docker-compose-usenet).

Essentially I have most things working (I can see plex and ombi on there respective ports) but I don't want to have to adjust the ports of the Unraid webui (port 80 and 443) instead I would rather give the docker container running traefik it's own routable IP (something like 192.168.1.253) then I would setup the router to port forward to that IP (on 80 and 443).

Then the proxy would point to the services running on the Unraid box (192.168.1.254) and the ports they are bound to (32400 for plex, etc...).

I have been messing with the `docker-compose.yaml` trying to create a network but have had no luck, I have tried this:

```
---
version: '3'

services:

  traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    command: --web --docker --docker.watch --docker.domain=${DOMAIN} \
             --docker.exposedbydefault=false --acme.domains=${DOMAIN} 
    container_name: traefik
    hostname: traefik
    #ports:
      #- "80:80"
      #- "443:443"
    networks:
      local:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.1.253
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${CONFIG}/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
      - ${CONFIG}/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - ${CONFIG}/traefik/.htpasswd:/etc/traefik/.htpasswd:ro
    labels:
      traefik.enable: "true"
      traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:monitor.${DOMAIN}"
      traefik.port: "8080"
      traefik.frontend.auth.basic: "${HTPASSWD}"
      com.ouroboros.enable: "true"
    restart: unless-stopped
    # Other services would be here...

networks:
  local:
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Creating network "setup_local" with the default driver
ERROR: Pool overlaps with other one on this address space
```

I have also tried with `driver: bridge` but this just gives the following:

```
Creating network "setup_local" with the default driver
ERROR: plugin "bridge" not found
```

The other thing I tried was removing the network stuff and adding these lines to the `command` section:

```
-p 192.168.1.253:80:80
```

This threw no errors but when I navigate to `192.168.1.253` it serves nothing?

I am fairly new to this so I don't really know where to look for logs (I am running pfSense on the router).

UPDATE:

After following @0x76 suggesting and adding an IP (`ip addr add 192.168.1.253 dev eth0`) I updated the ports config to the following:

```
ports:
  - "192.168.1.253:80:80"
  - "192.168.1.253:443:443"
```

But now I am receiving the following error:

```
ERROR: for traefik  Cannot start service traefik: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint traefik (b0377ca8df24ccda2dc6d798ad3ebb190edf4a2e08eda29f21c288b19ef1bc8c): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.1.253:80: bind:address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 2):

The Unraid box currently only has the one IP associated with it so therefore just adding that ip in your docker config won't work.

You could add this IP to your unraid box by adding an extra IP to the network interface, the command for this would be: `ip addr add 192.168.1.253 dev IF` where IF is the network interface you would like to add that IP to.

after that using `-p 192.168.1.253:80:80` would probably work.

Comment: Hey @0x76 that get's me further, now if I navigate to 192.168.1.253 I get the Unraid UI, I tried `ip addr add 192.168.1.253 dev eth0` and `ip addr add 192.168.1.253 dev eth1` both cause the Unraid Web UI to show, even if the traefik container is running and using `-p 192.168.1.253:80:80` in the `docker-compose.yaml`.  

As a side note I also removed https redirects from my `traefik.toml` as I realized I am only binding port 80 while testing.

Comment: Updated my original post with more information.

Comment: It seems like unraid is trying to listen on all local addreses, I am not familiar with unraid but you probably need to specify it to only listen on 192.168.1.254 so that treafik can use the other ip